# Configuring Google Workspace (Gmail) to trust a Mail Relay via ARC?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, g-suite

I am building a system which modifies incoming emails body on the fly (for example, it deletes attachements with viruses). Of course, I break the DKIM signature when there is one. Is it possible to configure GMail (Google Workspace) to use ARC and trust my system (a mail relay)?

For example, if an email from StackOverflow is correctly signed, then received/modified/signed by my system, and transferred to Gmail, I don't want Gmail to trigger any warning.

I am aware that https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8617.html is still experimental.